# After update to Android 6.0, SQLite database crashes

Tags: android, sqlite

I use this code to work with SQLite.

Before I update to android 6.0, it works perfectly, but now it crashes.

in MyParam class

```
public static SQLiteDatabase dbMyCount;
public static String DB_Path_MyCount = "/sdcard/GMS/MyCount.db";
```

on MainActivity

```
MyParam.dbMyCount = this.openOrCreateDatabase(MyParam.DB_Path_MyCount, MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);
SQL  = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyCount(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Tdate VARCHAR,Cust VARCHAR,";
SQL += "Prog VARCHAR,CustCode VARCHAR,OpenCode VARCHAR,Memo VARCHAR)";
MyParam.dbMyCount.execSQL(SQL);
```

I also updated my manifast to this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But still got error:

> Error Code : 1294 (SQLITE_CANTOPEN_ENOENT) Caused By : Specified
>   directory or database file does not exist. (unknown error (code 1294):
>   Could not open database)

I searched the Web and could not find any answer or solution.

Thanks.

Comment: **NEVER HARDCODE PATHS**. If that database is really on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to build a path to it. If that database is really on [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), you need to move it to external storage or [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

Answer (score 1):

Please follow suggestion given by CommonsWare. But also for marshmallow i.e android 6.0 and above you need to ask for run time permissions. Please have a look at the link below

http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Only specifying in the manifest in not enough as per android's new runtime permissions.